# Score Matchbox Recommender Stuck or Throwing an Error

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I'm using the Score Matchbox Recommender set to recommend items from unrated items. This module will run for over 3 hours (I haven't tried longer) and not finish. It will work fine when I'm recommending from rated items to evaluate the recommender, but as soon as I switch to unrated it will run indefinitely. I'm currently using the split data module on already split data to get an even smaller sample of about 20,000 rows. Is this too much for this module to handle?

If I try to take the sample even smaller using the partition and sample module (yes I know it's not a recommender split), I immediately get an Exception 0000: Internal system error.

Any idea why it's taking so long/how to fix it?

Comment: What's the rating scale you're using? Lots of unique ratings, such as 1-100 scale, can cause the module to run slow. Also, could you share your experiment in Gallery?

Comment: The rating system is just 0-6. I can't share it in the Gallery because you can't publish currently running experiments to the gallery and they have to be run before you upload them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the "Filter Based Feature Selection" module and then removing all columns besides those found significant and the identifiers seemed to fix the issue.